# When is the idea of 'Time is Currency' first used?

Tags: history-of, strata

In the novel Strata instead of earning money you earn days, which act as a currency. Instead of paying for food etc with money you pay with 'days'.

*In Time* is a film with a similar concept where someone is giving away days. I thought Strata was the first instance of this, but I wasn't sure.

Is Strata the first instance of this, or is it older?

Comment: [Time Value of Money](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_value_of_money) :). This notion dates at least to Martín de Azpilcueta (1491–1586) of the School of Salamanca. Not directly identical but a related concept

Comment: Or, if you will, to the first pre-historic society who told a captured prisoner of war with another tribe/nation "you get to live for as long as you do slave labor for us". In the words of TVTropes, this trope is "Older than Bible"

Comment: @DVK Not as money but as currency, which you earn (and can then sell or drinks, food etc). In Strata the main character as lived for 200+ years by earning her days as a Planetary Engineer.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a wikipedia article on Time based Currency. It was used by Hannu Rajaniemi in *The Quantum Thief*. I can't find much more n it. There is also a system called [Time Banking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Banking) that is hypothetical except for a few relatively unknowable medical plans such as Elderplan(which rewarded the elderly that maintained a healthy lifestyle).
It is not actually a fictional concept, it has been implemented by various medical plans to varying degrees, though the first fiction I can find is called ["Repent Harlequin" said the ticktockman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Repent,_Harlequin!%22_Said_the_Ticktockman)

Comment: That's very close with the "Repent.." story but no one can earn more time. How does the Quantum Theif go?

Comment: *Quantum Thief* has a decent description and a few reviews at [GoodReads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7562764-the-quantum-thief) ... from what I can tell, it doesn't describe the concept of 'time as money', but even if it does include this notion, it was published in Sept 2010, which doesn't pre-date Pritchett's *Strata*. It *is* Pritchett's version of *Strata* in the question reference, right? I can't find a reference to time as money as relates to *Strata* either, but Pritchett's DOES have planetary engineers.